# Lagging in v-on:change

Tags: vue.js

I had an input with v-on:change directive in it to call some method I declared inside the Vue objects. But I realized there are delays in calling the method whenever the value is changed.

I reproduced it in here:

HTML

```
<div id="demo">    
    <input type="number" min=0 v-on:change="change">
    <p>{{num}}</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var data = {
    num:0
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data,
  methods: {
    change: function(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
      this.num = event.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lookman/4y2wmxot/2/

Comment: Use v-model if you want it to respond to every key press. Browsers don't fire a change event until the item loses focus.

Comment: updated the answer, to trigger the event on each change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no delay actually, unless you click outside the input field in result section, `on-change` will not be triggered. It is triggered when focus changes from the input field, as you have only one element this is triggered when you click manually in the result section.

If you just add one more component, like I did [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4y2wmxot/3/), and now you enter some value and press tab, you will see change immediately, you can do this in your fiddle also, enter value and press tab (which will remove focus)

### If you want to trigger on each change

You can use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead of [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event to trigger the method for each change.

> The DOM input event is fired synchronously when the value of an  or  element is changed.

Code changes:

```
<input type="number" min=0 v-on:input="change">
```

Update fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4y2wmxot/4/

Answer (score 2):

For this use case, you really should be using `v-model` anyways:

```
<div id="demo">    
    <input type="number" min=0 v-model="num">
    <p>{{num}}</p>
</div>
```

Then there's no need for the method at all:

```
var data = {
    num:0
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: data,
})
```

Comment: This example is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. I need to trigger a function to some additional actions everytime the value change.

Comment: @geckob Use `v-model` and a `watch` function, then.

Comment: Yes. Also possible that way

Answer (score 1):

try keyup instead change:

```
<input type="number" min=0 v-on:change="change">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lookman/4y2wmxot/2/

will you face any limitation to prevent you to use another kind of event?